# How to pass parameters from C # to assembler through registers?

Tags: c#, arrays, assembly, simd, calling-convention

I have the following problem. I want to write an application to edit two images on anaglyph. The main part of the application is written in C #, while the conversion algorithm in assembler.
As parameters in the function, I pass a two-dimensional rgb byte array, where `array [0] []` refers to the first image and `array [1] []` refers to the second. In addition, I pass a second array (start and end) where the algorithm should start its work and stop (I need it for multithreading).

The function call in **C#** is as follows: (Writing in advance, I converted arrays in the method with "unsafe" keyword to pointers.)

```
[DllImport("ASM_DLL.dll")]
public static extern void AnaglyphColour(int **bitmaps, int* coords);

case true:
                   AnaglyphColour(intBitmapList, coordsPtr);
                   for (int i = 0; i < leftImageInformation.imageByteArrayAsm.Length; ++i)
                   {
                       leftImageInformation.imageByteArrayAsm[i] = (byte)intBitmapList[0][i];
                   }
                   leftImageInformation.finishAsm();
                   EventImageFinished(leftImageInformation.imageBitmap);
                   break;
```

However, the file written in asm looks like this so far:

```
.data

Colour  STRUCT 4     ;structure of the pixel color values
 r         DD  ?    ; red colour
 g         DD  ?    ; green colour
 b         DD  ?    ; blue colour
 a         DD  ?
Colour      ENDS    


;************************************
; Constants declarations
;************************************
.const 

pixelSize DD 3       ; pixel size in bytes

;************************************
; Algorithms
;************************************
.code

AnaglyphColour PROC USES ebx edx ecx,
                   images: PTR PTR DWORD,
                   coords: PTR DWORD

LOCAL       firstIndex: DWORD, lastIndex: DWORD,
           rgbLeft: Colour, rgbRight: Colour

   mov ebx, [coords]
   mov ecx, pixelSize

   mov eax, [ebx + 0*SIZEOF DWORD]
   mul ecx                     

   mov firstIndex, eax                 

   mov eax, [ebx + 1*SIZEOF DWORD] 
   mul ecx                         
   mov lastIndex, eax                  

   mov eax, [images]               
   mov ebx, [eax + 0*SIZEOF DWORD] 
   mov edx, [eax + 1*SIZEOF DWORD]

   mov ecx, firstIndex

algorithmLoop:
   MOVDQU xmm1, [ebx + ecx*SIZEOF DWORD]
   MOVDQU xmm2, [edx + ecx*SIZEOF DWORD]

   MOVDQU [rgbLeft], xmm1
   MOV [rgbLeft.Colour].b, 0
   MOV [rgbLeft.Colour].r, 0
   MOVDQU xmm1, [rgbLeft]  

   MOVDQU [rgbRight], xmm2             
   MOV [rgbRight.Colour].g, 0
   MOVDQU xmm2, [rgbRight]

   ADDPS xmm1, xmm2

   MOVDQU [ebx + ecx*SIZEOF DWORD], xmm1     

   add ecx, pixelSize  
   cmp ecx, lastIndex

jne algorithmLoop       

   ret                         

AnaglyphColour ENDP
```

The algorithm takes 2 colours from the right image (second image) and assigns it to the left image (first image). The code works and returns a valid image. The algorithm uses SIMD vector instructions.
The problem is that the arguments are passed as parameters. However, I need them to be transmitted through registers.

I don't know how to pass two arrays (two-dimensional and one-dimensional) through registers instead of parameters.

Comment: 64-bit code uses a register-args calling convention.  If you weren't writing legacy 32-bit code you wouldn't have a problem.  You could maybe declare your function as `fastcall` or `vectorcall` though, if C# supports that.

Comment: BTW, your SIMD code is very inefficient.  Use `andps` to zero some elements, not store / scalar store / vector reload.  That leads to a store-forwarding stall (extra latency) and costs many more uops than one `andps`.  Outside the loop you don't need `firstIndex`; I think you could just load args in a different order.  And using `mul` instead of `imul eax, ecx` is also inefficient.  You should compare this to the asm you get from a compiler with intrinsics.